# QTP Recovery scenario used to "skip" consecutive FAILED steps with 0 timeout -- how can I restore original timeout value?

Tags: timeout, automated-tests, qtp, gui-testing

Suppose I use QTPs recovery scenario manager to set the playback synchronization timeout to 0. The handler would return with "continue with next statement".

I'd do that to make sure that any following playback statements don't waste their time waiting for the next non-existing/non-matching step before failing:

I have a lot of GUI tests that kind of get stuck because let's say if 10 controls are missing, their (consecutive) playback steps produce 10 timeout waits before failing. If the playback timeout is 30 seconds, I loose 10x30 seconds=5 minutes execution time while it really would be sufficient to wait for 30 seconds ONCE (because the app does not change anymore -- we waited a full timeout period already).

Now if I have 100 test cases (=action iterations), this possibly happens 100 times, wasting 500 minutes of my test exec time window.

That's why I come up with the idea of a recovery scenario function setting the timeout to 0 after/upon the first failed playback step. This would accelerate the speed while skipping the rightly-FAILED step, yet would not compromise the precision/reliability of identifying the next matching GUI context (which creates a PASSED step).

Then of course upon the next *passed* playback step, I would want to restore the original timeout value. How could I do that? *This is my question.*

One cannot define a recovery scenario function that is called for PASSED steps.

I am currently thinking about setting a method function for Reporter.ReportEvent, and "sniffing" for PASSED log entries there. I'd install that method function in the scenario recovery function which sets timeout to 0. Then, when the "sniffer" function senses a ReportEvent call with PASSED status during one of the following playback steps, I'd reset everything (i.e. restore the original timeout, and uninstall the method function). (I am 99% sure, however, that .Click and .Set methods do not call ReportEvent to write their result status...so this option might probably not work.)

Better ideas? This really bugs me.

Comment: I can forget about the Report.ReportEvent idea because RegisterUserFunc only works for test object methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you tests aren't designed correctly, if you fail to find an object why do you continue?

One possible (non recovery scenario) solution would be to use `RegisterUserFunc` to override the methods you are using in order to do an `obj.Exist(0)` before running the required method.

```
Function MyClick(obj)
    If obj.Exist(1) Then
        obj.Click        
    Else
        Reporter.ReportEvent micFail, "Click failed, no object", "Object does not exist"
    End If
End Function

RegisterUserFunc "Link", "Click", "MyClick"
RegisterUserFunc "WebButton", "Click", "MyClick"
''# etc
```

Comment: Yeah, thought about that too, but since I cannot predict what object classes my team members will cover in their scripts, I'd have to add a (or many) RegisterUserFunc for every newly covered class. And what about the other operations doing a timeout if the target object is not found, like checkpoints etc. You cannot register a hook for those.

Comment: >>It sounds to me like you tests aren't designed correctly, if you fail to find an object why do you continue?<<

Well, just want to avoid aborting the hole test (or even test case) altogether. For example, non-mandatory fields in an entry mask that have been removed from the application's form should not lead to the test not attempting all the remaining test case steps. You see, currently QTP waits for each missing control, timing out after 30 seconds. Later, it resynchs. I just want to get rid of the useless delays, but keep the useful ones (and the continue-after-failed-steps behavior).

Comment: @TheBlastOne are you familiar with `Optional` steps?

Comment: @TheBlastOne look up `OptionalStep` (I got the name wrong in my previous comment) in the documentation

Comment: Sure I did that. Just came back to report that OptionalStep will not really help -- all it does is suppress the FAILED or runtime error status in the log. It does do the timeout repeatedly, AND it is ugly (OptionalStep.TestObject -- Whaat???). (And strange: The step after the optional step is optional too, I do not know why.) But worth a look, thanks.

Comment: I now believe that the only way to go would be the RegisterUserFunc trick being done for all reply methods of all test object classes I do. I'm not sure if I will implement it, but it surely is a valid answer with no feasable alternatives insight. Thanx Motti.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many controls of which some may be missing and you know that after 10 seconds you mentioned (when the first timeout occurs), nothing more will show up, then you can use the exists method with a timeout parameter.
Something like this:

```
timeout = 10

For Each control in controls
  If control.exists(timeout) Then
    do something with the control
  Else
    timeout = 0
  End If
Next
```

Now only the first timeout will be 10 seconds. Each and every subsequent timeout in your collection of controls will have the timeout set to 0 which will save your time.